# Emacs Python Mode Not Showing Ending Block

Tags: python, emacs, emacs24, python-mode, python.el

In Emacs 24.2, in python-mode when hitting tab to indent, it prints out at the bottom which block this level closes.

In Emacs 24.3 (which I believe updates python-mode to use python.el), this does not happen anymore. It usually prints something like: `Closes: class Hi():`. Is this not supported in the new python.el in Emacs 24.3? Is there anyway I can get it working again?

I tried searching for this but I cannot find any discussion or anything about it.

Comment: Mmm.... this is working for me (24.3) for "else" "elif" "except" and "finally" block closing words.  Could you describe a little bit how was it working for you in emacs 24.2?

Comment: If emacs 24.2 supports "def" and "class" closing words... then I can tell by looking at the source code that python.el in emacs 24.3 does not support them.  I would suggest a feature request for python.el maintainer.

Comment: @juanleon It doesn't even work for if and elif for elif for me. I stared it without init file and it doesn't work either. How come it works for everything in the older python-mode? Anyway I can get that?

Comment: Yes, you can download and install the last version of python-mode if you prefer it to python.el.  Use `M-x package-install`, for instance. It should be on main repos.  Strange that the "elif" is not working for you, though...